# Restrict access to documents associated with a certain term

Tags: 2013, taxonomy, term-store

I need to restrict access to all documents that are associated with a certain term only to some users. This should be done for both existing documents, and future documents, on upload.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out of the box way to do this.

You should use either a workflow or an event receiver. The idea is to handle `ItemAdded` event or `Start workflow on item create or Update`.

Inside you should remove permission of the item if Term has particular value. Once permission inheritance is broken, you can give permission only to respective users.

Note - The total number of unique permission has a limit 10,000+. So make sure in future this limit won't cause other issues.

Comment: What about the existing documents in the library?

Comment: @enb081 You can use PowerShell script and update permissions of existing items. Or manually start workflow for those items using PowerShell.